# Best practise to apply HTTPS for Webservice

Tags: web-services, apache, tomcat, https

Im working on the developpment of webservices in JAVA implemented with CXF 2.5.2. 
Im using apache Tomcat as web server.

I need to add HTTPS Security in some webservice method, i would like to know the best to implement HTTPS Security.
I heard that I can configure HTTPS in web.xml by specifing security constraint...or I can configure HTTPS in Apache tomcat for any method.

My ideas about advantage and disadvantage about each solution,
I think the advantage to configure https in web.xml is to localize in the same webapp of webservice.
The advantage in apache tomcat configuration let to not be coupled to any webapp.

Iam sure there is more way to implement HTTPS.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Configuring security in web.xml ( for example )

```
<security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>REST Service </web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>User</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <realm-name>Test</realm-name>
   </login-config>
   <security-role>
      <role-name>User</role-name>
   </security-role>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mad-d, however i know how to do it, i would like to know the best way to implement HTTPS (apache tomcat or web.xml), the advantage and disadvantage, which is the best way (performance, coupling, technically...)